# framework independent way to swap variables for deploy and dev envs

Tags: command-line-interface

Some easy way to change variables in code that is framework/language independent. Variables maybe url, usrname:password, and something can easily grep by regex. I am not looking for a python script, but something more like a config file + a cli tool. Is there anything like that?

Comment: [sed](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: thanks, I will look into it. Not sure how easy or hard to run sed on windows